# Disk Is Full Error When Copying Large Folders Onto Empty HDD

Tags: hard-drive, backup, disk-utility, hdd

Bought myself a brand new Seagate HDD (formatted in exFAT). I tried copying over a bunch of folders to back up (160 GB worth) and I am met with the below error message. This is strange, because there is absolutely nothing on the HDD. I tried reformatting it to Mac OS Extended (Journaled) thinking it would help since that format is optimized for Mac OS, but unfortunately, I am met with the same error message. How can I get around this? By the way this is on Big Sur.

It seems to be an issue with my Macbook itself, since I cannot copy large folders after trying a separate HDD.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Can you add to your question, DDE connected, the results of the terminal command : ``diskutil list``.
And  indicate the Mac model as well as the type of connection of your DDE (USB/Thunderbolt etc...)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! It was a pesky icloud issue. Some files within the gigantic 160GB folder I was trying to transfer were not downloaded to my Mac's internal SSD disk, and instead were stored in icloud. When transferring the files, it appears that icloud must first download the files onto the internal SSD, and then once downloaded it will copy to the external HDD. The issue was that I barely had any space left on my Mac's internal SSD (only 52 mb!), so when I tried copying the large folder onto the external HDD, it would fail to download the files stored in icloud because my SSD only had 52mb left.

I suppose when the error message says "The operation can't be completed because the *disk* is full", Apple is saying that the *disk* is the *SSD*, and that icloud failed to download the files from the cloud before the transfer. Very misleading error message since I definitely thought *disk* was referring to the external HDD!